# Statisical Analysis for results (slope, min und max)

Tags: r

My data comes from an enzyme measurement. I measure 3 different enzyme activities (A, B, and C) over time. I have in each of these measurements 4 groups (apo_control, apo_needle, sym_control, sym_needle) with several individuals. Then I calculated the slope using a GLM model on the basis of the entire data set, as well as the min and max values from the mean values of the individuals.
Now I have a data set with the results that looks like this:

data set "Results":

```
structure(list(Messung = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), SymStatus = c("apo", "apo", "sym", 
"sym", "apo", "apo", "sym", "sym", "apo", "apo", "sym", "sym"
), treat = c("control", "needle", "control", "needle", "control", 
"needle", "control", "needle", "control", "needle", "control", 
"needle"), Steigung = c(-3.586e-05, 1.551e-05, -2.939e-05, 1.707e-05, 
0.000124, 0.0001677, 8.115e-05, 0.0001056, 0.0002925, 0.0002661, 
0.0003487, 0.0001654), Gruppe = c("apo_control", "apo_needle", 
"sym_control", "sym_needle", "apo_control", "apo_needle", "sym_control", 
"sym_needle", "apo_control", "apo_needle", "sym_control", "sym_needle"
), min_means = c("0.05190", "0.04006", "0.04371", "0.03993", 
"0.05843", "0.05145", "0.05420", "0.04852", "0.07864", "0.08125", 
"0.07981", "0.07040"), max_means = c("0.05762", "0.04970", "0.04999", 
"0.05114", "0.07303", "0.06988", "0.06343", "0.06303", "0.11212", 
"0.11076", "0.11673", "0.08983")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would now like to do a static compairise, but am unsure which test to take. I have tried it this way until now:

```
RESULTSA <- subset(results, results$mess == "A")
RESULTSB <- subset(results, results$mess == "B")
RESULTSC <- subset(results, results$mess == "C")
kruskal.test(RESULTSA$Steigung~RESULTSA$Gruppe)
kruskal.test(RESULTSA$min_means~RESULTSA$Gruppe)
kruskal.test(RESULTSA$max_means~RESULTSA$Gruppe)
```

The result for all three measurements on slope, min and max is that there is no difference between the groups. I tried the Krustal-Wallis-test, because I was nor sure if the data is parametic or not.
I wonder if these are the actual results or if I have made a mathematical error.

Maybe there is someone who can fix the problem, unfortunately I have not found a similar question in this forum.

Comment: Relevant [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Try converting your min & max results to numeric ?

Comment: Can I do this mathematically, just compare this slope, min and max from 4 groups? 
Is the test used correct? 
And also with compairing the min and max of A I get the extakt the same p-wert as result, can that be right???

Comment: @Ben Bolker that unfortunately makes no difference

Comment: You shouldn't reduce the data to summary statistics. If you have only one aggregated data point (e.g. minimum) for each group, you can't do a statistical comparison.  (Asking whether the minima or maxima of two groups are statistically significantly different is possible, if you start from the full sample, but challenging.)